# Fire code everytime camera position changes in three.js

Tags: three.js

How do I trigger code everytime my camera position changes?

This is what I have so far:

```js
camera.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  // my code
});
```

Comment: AFAIK cameras do not fire a change event. What sort of camera is it? Why not just fire your code when you change the camera position?

Comment: @2pha technically im not entirely sure how to do this. I could basically create two variables: oldPosition and currentPosition. Check the first against the second and see if the difference is anything other than 0, if it is then the camera is moving. Then if the oldPosition - CurrentPosition equals a positive number then the camera is going backwards. If the difference is negative then the camera is heading forwards.

Comment: @2pha would you say my logic makes sense?

Comment: So why cannot you just run you code in the moment you check difference between positions?

Comment: If you are writing the code that does the actual moving of the camera, like I and kaigorodov said, just run your code there instead if a change listener.

Comment: Asperger, your logic makes sense, but there is no "oldPosition" variable. Like 2pha says, you can do something like camera.hasChanged = true; in your code that actually updates the camera. Later, check camera.hasChanged. hasChanged is a variable you create (you can add arbitrary variables , may want to pre-set it to false at the start up as well.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using [OrbitControls.js](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls), to control the camera, then that library fires a change event when it's update function causes the camera to zoom, pan or rotate;

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L203

So for example, you can use something like this to respond to when the camera moves;

```js
function onPositionChange(o) {
  console.log("position changed in object");
  console.log(o);
}

controls.addEventListener('change', onPositionChange);
```

Comment: BTW, the values I wanted out of here to copy pan/rotation were target and object.position, so--

`function onPositionChange(evt)
{     
 var control = evt.target;
 console.log(control);
 console.log(control.target);
 console.log(control.object.position);     
}`

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in comments you should check the change yourself

rendering with THREE goes in frames - you have your render loop and call

```
renderer.render();
```

inside of it
simply create another camera and copy to it from your real camera after each render

this way you keep your state and after doing stuff with camera just check if the camera changed

```
var camera2 = camera.clone()
render()
{
    doStuffWithCamera();
    var cameraChanged = compareCameras(camera, camera2);
    if(cameraChanged)
    {
         //execute code you want to when camera changed
    }
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
    camera2.copy(camera);
}
```

in compareCameras you should compare the projectionMatrix , position, matrix, zoom etc.(look at the Object3D parameters and Camera parameters and experiment a bit)

with code like this you can create a lazy rendering loop that renders only when camera changed highering your average FPS by a bit

attatching an event to camera change would be bad as it can be changed multiple times in a single frame (for example gravity moves it down, user moves mouse to change rotation and has key pressed that also changes position - 3 sources of change that can occur more than once every frame) - you would call your code very often and probably redundantly

Answer (score -1):

Update:
Note that in some of the controls this functionality was not available in three.js as I was writing this answer (not sure if it is available now).

three.js uses [EventDispatcher](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/EventDispatcher) for this purpose. You can take a look how it is implemented inside the [OrbitControls](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls). The idea is to check the camera position/rotation change using a small threshold value and fire a `dispatchEvent` as soon as the condition is satisfied. So this is how you can implement it:

```js
if( lastPosition.distanceToSquared( scope.camera.position )   > 0.000001 ||
    8 * ( 1 - lastQuaternion.dot( scope.camera.quaternion ) ) > 0.000001 )
{
  scope.dispatchEvent( { type: 'change',
                         position: scope.camera.position } );

  // store position/quaternion for the next iteration
  lastPosition.copy( scope.camera.position );
  lastQuaternion.copy( scope.camera.quaternion );
}
```

To be able to dispatch events like this you have to make sure that you assign your custom object prototype with the EventDispatcher prototype as shown in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/EventDispatcher):

```js
Object.assign( Foo.prototype, EventDispatcher.prototype );
```

then you can add event listeners which will listen for your camera change events.

Answer (score -1):

The `.position` property of a Three.js object (f.e. `camera.position`) does not (currently) emit any event that you can listen to, so we can not (out of the box) observe changes to it.

However, we can patch the `.position` object of a camera (or the prototype of all `Vector3` instances, for example) to manually add an event system using Three's `EventDispatcher` class.

Here is an example:

```js
const {Vector3, EventDispatcher, PerspectiveCamera} = THREE

// Dynamically modify the Vector3 class so that now it will
// use THREE's event system (which is called EventDispatcher).
Object.assign(Vector3.prototype, EventDispatcher.prototype)

// Patch any method that you wish, so they will emit an event
// when you use them. Here we've only patched the `Vector3.set` method.
{
  // Get the reference to the original method.
  const original = Vector3.prototype.set
  
  // Define a new method that calls the old one, and also
  // emits an event.
  Vector3.prototype.set = function(...args) {
    // Call the original with any arguments, if any:
    const returnValue = original.apply(this, args)
    
    // Dispatch an event.
    this.dispatchEvent({type: 'change'})
    
    // Don't forget to return the original's return value,
    // if any:
    return returnValue
  }
}

// Now, as an example, let's make a new camera, and
// change its position every second, and write the
// position to the screen:
{
  // Update a camera's position every second.
  const camera = new PerspectiveCamera()
  setInterval(() => {
    // camera.position has a patched set() method.
    const pos = camera.position
    pos.set(pos.x + 1, pos.y + 2, pos.z + 3)
  }, 1000)
  
  // Listen to our new 'change' event on camera.position:
  const output = document.querySelector('pre')
  camera.position.addEventListener('change', () => {
    output.innerText = `
    Camera's position: {
      x: ${camera.position.x},
      y: ${camera.position.y},
      z: ${camera.position.z}
    }`
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.124.0/build/three.js"></script>

<pre>
    
    Camera's position: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 0
    }
</pre>
```